# How to pass parameters to functions on the fly in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
divResize = { myDiv:function(width, height)
 {...}

}
divResize.myDiv(100,400);
```

How would I get the latter arguments to be input received dynamically from the user say from a form or some other interactive element? What if these numbers aren't predetermined yet and I want them to be able to change something visual.

Comment: call function inside any kind of handler bound to an user interaction event. This is really really a basic question, you'd have better to read some tutos

Comment: Can you show a quick example of what you mean. I understand but need a visual... Its not for a project just trying to get my patterns right and seeing if there are other options I haven't considered.

Comment: Maybe you could show options you have already considered...

Comment: Its theoretical I'm just thinking I haven't considered anything just trying to learn... Its not for a project. More of a conversation piece.

Comment: @SunRhythms To complete your  question, mark one of the answers as your answer or write your own answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use inputs (probably with an id), then extract the values using something like `document.getElementById("input1").value` to pass in to the function.

HTML may look something like:

```
<input id="input1" type="number" />
<input id="input2" type="number"  />
<button onclick="mycode()">click</button>
```

Then js would be something along the lines of

```
function mycode(){
    var a = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("input2").value;
    divResize.myDiv(a,b);
}
```

Granted, in real life you'd probably want to check the inputs aren't empty & confirm they are numbers before passing them in to your function etc. You'd probably also want saner variable & function names than I've used.

Note: I typed this code straight in to here & haven't tested, so there may be typos/daft bugs in it.

Comment: your function doesn't have the arguments in this case would I need them?

Comment: Shouldn't do, in the above example the values wanted are pulled from the HTML inputs, so don't need to be provided to the function itself. (Reading some of the other answers, i'm starting to think i may have misunderstood your question though).

Comment: Carl he mixmatched it... he provided a roundabout solution while leaving the intended arguments out. (I'm guessing).

Answer (score 0):

You could add these input fields if you want that the user has control over the dimensions.

```
<input type="text" id="width">
<input type="text" id="height">
```

And than add this to you JavaScript function

```
var width = $("#width").val();
var height = $("#height").val();
```

Than you can use `width` and `height` for resizing the div.

You could also fire the resizing function like.

```
$("#width").change(function(){
  //your function code
  $("#myDivToResize").css("width",$(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the arguments variable as seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

For example:

```
function a(){
   console.log(arguments);
}

a(1,2,3,"foo","bar");
```

returns

```
[1,2,3,"foo","bar"]
```

so you could easily get the first argument by arguments[0], and so on.

Comment: I see what you are saying but I am trying to input the arguments more from an unknown. Think of it like I'm getting this numbers from a user whom could type whatever. How would I get what they typed to become an argument for a();

Comment: oh, then the other answers are exactly what you need. They are both really good.